# Can this code be made more concise?

Tags: design, clean-code

I came across some code recently where in many, many places, expression evaluations were being assigned to different arrays one index at a time. A psuedo-code example:

```
array[0] = item1[0] + item2[0];
array[1] = item1[1] + item2[1];
array[2] = item1[2] + item2[2];
```

or

```
array[0] /= variable;
array[1] /= variable;
array[2] /= variable;
```

My instinct would be to first create a function for iterating through an array and assigning an evaluation using a single for loop. Then secondly, just call that function with arguments for the array, a number defining how many indices to loop through and the items to be evaluated.

- Obviously, one obstacle to that method is the fact that the
  expressions being evaluated are arbitrary - they can be additions,
  subtractions, divisions, multiplications.
- And for another, the expression operands can be either variables or arrays, and of
  course in statically typed languages, the types could be varied.
- Also, the number of operands may be varied.

Is it possible to make this code more concise taking into account all possible cases, and what would the solution be called in technical terms?

Comment: Does the language you are coding in have first-class functional values and anonymous functions (i.e. lambda-expressions) i.e. [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)? If yes, you could map some closure to the array!

Comment: That's what I'm after, thank you (and @Frank). I'll look into anonymous functions and other FP tools.

Comment: Your examples could obviously be made more concise by using a loop. Can't you add an example to your question where you demonstrate the obstacles mentioned? Furthermore, the options for writing more concise code are heavily language dependent.

Comment: If I had wanted a language-dependent answer I'd have asked on Stack Overflow. Instead, it was a problem I have come across before and wanted to know what kind of problem it was and how they are best solved. Now that I have the technical terms I can write better code regardless of the language I use, although in many cases it may require trade-offs and approximations.

Comment: Venerable Fortran allows `array(:) = item1(:) + item2(:)`. Fortran compilers optimize it using vectorization features of CPUs. And Fortran does not plead guilty to functional programming.

Comment: @Orkwad: you missed the opportunity to give a better example, I have still problems to understand what you are after.

Comment: @DocBrown That's okay, I've received 2 satisfactory responses and I'm sure that future visitors to this page will get what they were looking for, should they happen to have a similar conundrum.

Comment: @jwenting In this case the actual point of the code was being obscured by impenetrable walls of text due to the many assignments. But you're absolutely right. Making code readable should be the goal over and above making it shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course it is :)

You are quite correct in that creating a loop already simplifies things, so let me address your more detailed concerns about it:

- Arbitrary expressions: while the expressions themselves may be arbitrary, they may still be representable as a function. When you are thinking in a more functional programming mindset, then you will realize, that all you're really doing is mapping a function over the array elements.
- Type difference: This is the reason, why we have polymorphism. When abstractly mapping over an array of type `T` with a function that returns `T`s, you don't have to mind the type difference really.
- Number of operands: This is captured by the first point above. As we only care about mapping a function over this array, we do not care about the number of that function's arguments.

So in general, my suggestion on how to simplify this would be to take a closer look at functional programming principles, in particular, higher-level functions (i.e. functions, which take another function as a parameter).

Note that FP may be the most direct and easiest way for simplifying it, but even if you are not working in a FP language (which is most likely anyways), its ideas are portable to most languages. You may however have invest more into supporting structures/classes, which may make the simplification look rather involved overall. But keep in mind, that high-level concepts like mapping a function over some elements are extremely reusable, hence, it may well be worth it to make a small investment up front.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what 'Frank' wrote, you build something like strategy , an `abstract Operator class` that its constructor takes two arguments and has a method of `myCalc` which returns the value.
Then have for each arithmetic or mathematical operation and derived class.
Using generics you can even have it get different Types as parameters.

Then at your code you write it like this:
`array[i] = calc(value1,value2,new plus())`

where calc is simply `return Op.calc(value1,value2)`

Comment: I personally believe this is the opposite of concise. It adds several layers of indirection and introduces little code reduction while making the code harder to read than a simple for loop. Your version also only works with tuples of values, but that could be addressed. Don't forget the most important dogma in writing code. KISS: Keep it simple, stupid!

Comment: Well generally i agree with you, but from the OP i understand that he wants to make the code: a. more generic. b. more readable. well this is where design patterns are the solutions. that doesn't mean this is how assignments should be done, but a suggestion that might solve his problem.